# tableView sortDescriptorsDidChange: not getting called

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sorting, nstableview

Greetings,

I have an NSTableView with two columns that works fine... except: If I set the sort descriptor for the table in Interface Builder, things work as expected and sortDescriptorsDidChange gets called as expected.  If, however, I *don't* set the sort descriptors in Interface Builder and instead use this:

```
[tableView setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:) ]autorelease]]];
```

(where "name" is the identifier for the leftmost column) in my code, sortDescriptorsDidChange never gets invoked.  As I read (misread?) Apple's documentation for NSTableView, what I am doing, I think, should work.  What am I doing wrong?

P.S.  I know that I could also use a NSArrayController for all this (and if I do it works fine), but for whatever reason, I have chosen not to.

Comment: at what point are you calling `setSortDescriptors`?  In my experience I've called it too early (like awake from nib) when the object (in your case `tableView`) wasn't instantiated yet

Comment: That's probably it.  I am calling setSortDescriptors in windowControllerDidLoadNib (I, perhaps mistakenly, thought that that was the correct place to do this sort of thing in a document-based application.)  I just checked, and after calling [myTableView setSortDescriptors], [myTabeView sortDescriptors] returns nil.  Where (when) is the correct place (time) to make this sort of a call (or should I ask a new question regarding the order things happen at window launch?)  Thanks!

Comment: Followup:  I moved the call to setSortDescriptors into a button press method.  Calling setSortDescriptors programmatically does cause sortDescriptorsDidChange to get called, but clicking on the table column header still doesn't.  Do I still need to set something else for this to work (an action for clicking on the column header or something)?  I thought from reading the documentation that such a thing wasn't necessary.

Comment: Check that `myTableView` is not `nil`. This should be true in both `awakeFromNib` and `windowControllerDidLoadNib:`; the former happens after all of your connections are hooked up, and the latter happens after the nib is fully loaded (i.e., *everything* is hooked up.

Comment: O.K...

(1) In windowControllerDidLoadNib: tableView is nil.

(2) I added a button to toggle sort order (simulating what I expect clicking on the tableView column header to do) and at that point: (a) tableView is non-nil, and (b) the setting the sort order using the code I posted in my original question works as expected causing sortDiscriptorsDidChange: to be invoked.  However actually clicking on the column header still does nothing.

So far, the only way I've been able to make table-sorting-by-clicking-on-column-header work is to specify it in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

it should work without this but have you tried sending the KVO notifications yourself ?

```
[tableView willChangeValueForKey:@"sortDescriptors"];
[tableView setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:) ]autorelease]]];
[tableView didChangeValueForKey:@"sortDescriptors"];
```

if you do not want to add the descriptors in IB you can do something like this

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)theColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
    //if we have no sort descriptor for this column create one based on it's identifier (instead of setting it for each in IB,saves time and prevents errors)
    NSSortDescriptor *desc = [theColumn sortDescriptorPrototype];
    if ([desc key] == nil) {
        NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:[theColumn identifier] ascending:YES];  
        [theColumn setSortDescriptorPrototype:sorter];
        [sorter release];
    }
}
```